# Can anyone please help me with this SQL Query (works in SQLite DB Browser, but not in Rails)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Rails has been spitting this out to me:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "﻿SELECT": syntax error: 
        SELECT questions.id, questions.text, questions.question_type_id, questions.meta, questions.max_answer_length,
          COUNT(form_questions.id) AS expr1,
          (5) AS expr2,
          CAST(COUNT(form_questions.id) AS REAL) / CAST((5) AS REAL) AS expr3
        FROM questions, form_questions
        WHERE form_questions.question_id = questions.id
        GROUP BY questions.id, questions.text, questions.question_type_id, questions.meta, questions.max_answer_length
        HAVING expr3 >= 0.75
        ORDER BY COUNT(form_questions.id) DESC;
```

The query executes correctly with no problems in the SQLite Database Browser, but for some reason Rails is baulking at it.

The code is:

```
  def self.find_by_commonality
    Question.find_by_sql(%&
        SELECT questions.id, questions.text, questions.question_type_id, questions.meta, questions.max_answer_length,
          COUNT(form_questions.id) AS expr1,
          (5) AS expr2,
          CAST(COUNT(form_questions.id) AS REAL) / CAST((5) AS REAL) AS expr3
        FROM questions, form_questions
        WHERE form_questions.question_id = questions.id
        GROUP BY questions.id, questions.text, questions.question_type_id, questions.meta, questions.max_answer_length
        HAVING expr3 >= 0.75
        ORDER BY COUNT(form_questions.id) DESC; & % [])
  end
```

WTF is it complaining about?

Comment: Does SQLLite have a monitoring tool so that you can see the exact string that is being submitted to the server? That might point you in the right direction.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that - since the server is a flat file, I'm not sure how that would work.

Comment: As @Staelen points out, there's a strange character immediately before the "S" of "SELECT" in the code you've posted here. I don't think it's actually a dot: if I copy-paste it into a text editor, I see a "?", so it's probably something unprintable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a **dot** in front of the SELECT statement, are you sure it should be there?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a string formatting issue. Try without skipping a line between the first parenthesis and the start of your SQL statement.